# Optical odometer

Tags: measurement, distance

For my device moving above the surface (railway tracks) I need to be measuring the distance traveled. So far I have been using a wheel with IRC (incremental rotary sensor). To simplify it I would like to use some kind of optical sensor that scans the surface.

I have seen some ideas using optical mouse sensors for the distance measurement, however, it is not clear to me where this would take the reference for determination of the actual distance by which the sensor has moved over the surface.

Is there any such optical sensor?

Comment: Could the wheels of the moving vehicle with a simple rotation counter? Or could the tracks themselves be relied on to provide a consistent reference such as the seams between rail segments or some other feature which pre-exists in the rail fabrication?l

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is called optical flow sensor. There is a also a free source community (not sure) that develops and sells such device. https://pixhawk.org/modules/px4flow

https://pixhawk.org/_media/modules/px4flow_paper.pdf

For example you could mount the camera on top of the railway wagon with known distance from ground and illuminate the surface with LED lamp (if you wish to measure at low light). Such setup will be more precise if the surface isn't flat, all you have to do is to use lens with more magnification. More height -> more magnification -> better precision.

But you can make it from scratch using optical mouse sensor with adapted lens.

Comment: @user2165039 Lots of red light might be required as Marko has suggested. Camera frame rates change with light level, and you likely need high frame rates to avoid aliasing ("wagon-wheels-rotating-backwards" in old movies). Focussing properly is critical - a generic mouse lens focus is much too close.

Answer (score 1):

A displacement sensor will need a fixed reference point to measure off of to gather repeatable data. If you've only got a linear track this could work, but I expect that's not the case. A common way to approach this is an encoder. An optical rotary encoder mounted to one of the wheels would work well, is inexpensive, and robust.

An alternative is a linear encoder. These are used when you want to remove any sources of error when converting from the rotational measurement to actual distance traveled. Instead of having a grid that's measured each rotation, you measure against a linear grid that's along the entire path of travel. These are extremely accurate and also quite a bit more costly.

Given all these constraints a better rotary encoder seems like the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

the optical sensing found in mice generally is not much more than taking successive pictures of the ground with a low-resolution camera, and correlating (shifting them across each other) them until you've found a maximum match. That gives you an amount of pixel displacement.

From that pixel displacement, with the fixed distance between camera and surface, it's easy to infer a travelled distance.

Now, for railway tracks, I'd expect you have some variance in the distance between optical sensor and ground. (suspensions, different state and shape of ground); so you'll need both a system to measure the instantaneous distance between sensor and ground and the pixel displacement.

That should be easy to build using two cameras mounted at a fixed distance next to each other, and really common image processing libraries (OpenCV comes to mind, which is free and pretty much a de-facto standard in its discipline). The two cameras will give you depth information, and you can then use the camera imagery and the tools for calculating optical flow between successive images to measure the distance travelled.

If you're already familiar with OpenCV, and have two webcams lying around, sounds like a two-day project to come up with a proof of concept. Getting two cameras to be perfectly synchronous and fast enough, in an enclosure rugged enough for railway usage, also containing the computation platform, and with suitable illumination, on the other hand, sounds like fully fledged product development task.

If you can't, for mechanical reasons, have two cameras, one camera might be enough, if you know the width of the rails – you can use that width in the images to continously calibrate the camera's height, and then use the calculated height to the pixel displacement to real-world distance relation.

In any case, have fun calibrating stuff :)

You might, also, just use something like a hall sensor mounted close to the rail or the wheels, and infer speed from the signals you're observing with that, or rather, from the derivative of them, really easily.

Comment: Actually you don't need cameras; two lightdetectors ("1 pixel cameras") can be enough; depending on the required accuracy and minimum speed involved.

Comment: @Curd I suppose simply by looking at how fast the reflectivity changes?

Comment: By speed I meant speed of the moving device. E.g. if OP doesn't care about displacement caused by movement < 0.1m/s and memory is big enough to store 10s of signal then it's enough to have just two simple light (or any other location related signal) sensors 1m apart.

Comment: @Curd so you mean lights mounted to the tracks every 1m and a light sensor on the wagon? To be honest, I didn't consider any systems that would require modifications to the rails, since that sounds infeasible.

Comment: no just two light sensors looking at the ground (between the tracks) measuring the reflectivity 1m apart in direction of movement. If the signals correlate (one beeing delayed by a known about of time; e.g. max. 10s) you know that the train has moved by 1m.

Comment: @Curd aaah, right :) yeah, unlike a mouse, the train has one dimension less freedom of movement!